# Tensorflow Type Error

Tags: python, tensorflow

Getting strange type error with TensorFlow code:

```
curMaxAbs = tf.Variable(-1.0, tf.float32)
maxi = tf.Variable(-1, tf.int32)
for i, g in enumerate(grads):
    maxG = tf.reduce_max(tf.abs(g))            
    oCurMaxAbs = curMaxAbs            
    curMaxAbs = tf.cond(tf.greater(maxG,oCurMaxAbs),
                        lambda: maxG,
                        lambda: oCurMaxAbs)
    maxi = tf.cond(tf.greater(maxG,oCurMaxAbs),
                   lambda: maxi,
                   lambda: i)
```

Getting the error for line `if not tf.equal(curMaxAbs,tf.maximum(curMaxAbs, maxG))`

> TypeError: Input 'y' of 'Maximum' Op has type float32 that does not
>   match type int32 of argument 'x'

How in the world could `curMaxAbs` have type `int32`, when it is only reassigned with the `curMaxAbs = tf.maximum(curMaxAbs, maxG)` statement, and the `tf.maximum` function returns the same type as the first argument? (per https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/maximum).

Comment: This piece of code did not throw any errors. Is there something else you might have done?
```
import tensorflow as tf
curMaxAbs = tf.Variable(-1, tf.float32)
maxi = -1
for i, g in enumerate([1,2,3]):
    maxG = tf.reduce_max(tf.abs(g))
    if tf.equal(curMaxAbs,tf.maximum(curMaxAbs, maxG)) is not None:
        curMaxAbs = tf.maximum(curMaxAbs, maxG)
        maxi = i
```

Comment: @gidim Thanks - This is part of a neural network optimization routine, so lots of other things going on, not sure exactly where the issue might be.  Could any setting of `glist` change your result?  I don't think so, right?  I guess that's my point - dont' see any path where this wouldn't be correct...

Comment: It's likely not a TF bug if it works on my machine.. put a breakpoint an keep examining the type of `curMaxAbs`

Comment: On the line `maxi=-1`, I have `curMaxAbs.dtype == <dtype: 'int32_ref'>`.  However, when I change the first line to `curMaxAbs = tf.Variable(-1, tf.float32)`, the type is instead `<dtype: 'float32_ref'>` (and seems to fix the issue).  Seems like the initial value is somehow overriding the type?